# "The response sent by the skill was invalid. Use JSON schema validation to validate the skill response " issue while accessing from alexa skill

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, aws-iot, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am creating a virtual device for checking the connection and I am following this link for reference:
[developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/implement-skill-tutorial.html](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/implement-skill-tutorial.html)

They are giving this link to verify JSON: [Link to verify JSON](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-smarthome/wiki/Validation-Schemas)

After check on that page result, There is no defect found in JSON.
[image: image 1]
Test cases result
[image: image 2]
[image: image4]

Code and response
[image: image5]

[image: image 6]
Response
[image: image 7]
[image: iamge8]

Please help me to solve this problem or please give me any suggestion to solve this issue. This is virtual device

Comment: Relevant code and config should be in the question as formatted text as opposed to links to images of formatted text.